# What mock object framework should I use when developing in Python on the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, mocking

I am developing an application on the Google App Engine using Python (and Django, if that matters).

Which mock object framework should I help to assist with unit tests? I see there are a number of standalone projects (i.e. http://python-mock.sourceforge.net), but I'm not sure if there's something built-in that I can use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use this [mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) extensively and very happy with it. It is small, simple and expressive.

And yes, there is no mock-framework in the standard Python library.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it out. Looks like there's better documentation than the sourceforge one I tried.

Comment: Some feedback... I've finally started using this. Very nice!